# How to remove an object literals from an array of object literals by object

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the most general methodology (possibly in javascript) to remove an "object literal" from an array of "objects literal", I mean how to determine what the index of the object to be removed is.

The keys are the same, only the values can change.

Lets suppose we have

```
arrObj = [{k: "a"},{k: "b"},{k: "c"},{k: "d"}]; //{k: "a"}
```

is just an example of oject literals, but each object could be also more nested like this

```
{k: "a", {y: {z: "c"}} }
```

I want to define a function literal which is able to make this stuff:

```
var removeObjFromArray = function (obj){ ... };    
arrObj.removeObjFromArray({k: "b"}); // {k: "a"},{k: "c"},{k: "d"}
```

Comment: You do not have an "array of object literals". You have an array of objects. Each object was created from an object literal, which is the lexical notation -- the sequence of characters, hence "literal" -- that you typed into your code.

Comment: And what is a function literal?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a much better way of doing whatever it is you're doing.  To achieve the solution you want here, you need to iterate over the array and *then* compare the object.  One solution is to use JSON, although you would see a performance hit in older browsers that need the [compatibility shim](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).  This is only a viable solution if you don't need to compare functions.  Something like this should work:

```
function removeFromArray(arr, obj) {
    obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    for (var i=0, max = arr.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (JSON.stringify(arr[i]) === obj)
            arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

> **Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4JmzV/**

Note that, as *cdhowie* mentions in the comments, order of iteration is a factor with JSON and object properties would need to be defined in the same order.  However, without JSON, you'd have to iterate over each object's keys *and* iterate over the object passed in the argument several times to ensure both objects contain the same keys and same values, making it a more complex task and much slower vs native JSON.

As I said in my first sentence, *"There's probably a much better way of doing whatever it is you're doing"*, and you might be better off taking another look at your approach.

Comment: Does `JSON.stringify()` guarantee the order that key-value pairs will appear in the output string?  If the order is not predictable, this code may fail on otherwise-identical objects.

Comment: @cdhowie: with the compatibility implementation, most browsers would require that the object keys are defined in the same order.  As for the the native implementations, I'm not sure but I would guess that the same applies.  Either way, it's a good point and would require a little researching before a proper implementation.  I still think it's a decent solution, as comparing objects would be much more complex.  However, I do think it's likely that the OP could avoid needing to do this entirely and take a better approach to solve his problem.

Comment: Understood.  It's a good approach provided that key ordering is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define when two objects are "the same". In your example, the argument to `removeObjFromArray` is actually a different object (if compared by reference) than the object in the array, since each literal syntax creates a distinct object.

If you know they always have a key named "k", you can compare on that, but I guess you are looking for a more general solution?

You could decide that two objects are the same if they have the same properties with the same values (recursively compared in the case of objects). But it really depends on the uses cases for your program.